# How to implement feature search in OpenLayers with Geoserver?

Tags: postgis, openlayers-2, geoserver

I'm looking to build an application similar to [this](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/demos/find/find_map_datagrid.html) ArcGIS Server JS example which does a find task against a layer in the map. However i want to do this with OpenLayers, Geoserver and PostGIS. Some pointers would be great.

Regards

Med

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with OpenLayers, Geoserver and PostGIS and **Geodjango** too. There is a tutorial [here](http://invisibleroads.com/tutorials/geodjango-googlemaps-build.html#id10). if you desing a good database with logical index, you can get search tool as google map.

i hope it helps you.